# Grabbing elements turns them into strings

Tags: jquery

So this works:

```
var ship = $(".ship");
console.log(ship.offset());
```

This does not work:

```
var ships = $(".ships");
console.log(ships[0].offset());
```

When I `console.log(ships[0])`, i get the div as a string and not an object.
What am I missing?

Comment: share your html please, your script means close to nothing without the html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `ships[0]` it returns the actual DOM element from the jQuery object `ships`. You can't use jQuery methods on a DOM element itself

If you want the first element as a jQuery object use `eq(index)` or `first()`

```
console.log(ships.eq(0).offset());
/* or */
console.log(ships.first().offset());
```